# No Ethernet connection after a failure to install CUDA with JetPack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ethernet, cuda

After downloading Jetpack 3, I tried to flash the Jetson and install CUDA 8.
I tried to install using two different computers (wifi turned off).
I wasn't able to install CUDA, I had an error.
For both computers, after the failure during the installation, the ethernet connexion doesn't work anymore.
I checked and compared with another computer the `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` files.

My config is Ubuntu 16.04LTS, Jetson TX2, Jetpack 3.
Computer and Jetson connected to a hub, connected to Internet.

For now, I try to recover the Ethernet connection on my computer.
Now, My computer is plugged into a hub which is connected to a DHCP server. (The Jetson TX2 is unplugged and JetPack not running).

I tried these commands to figure out what was wrong.

**$ ifconfig eth0** (when I try to connect eth0)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:f1:0e:48:52:d2  
      inet6 addr: 2607:f810:c20:16:2af1:eff:fe48:52d2/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::2af1:eff:fe48:52d2/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:17525 errors:0 dropped:104 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:366 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:84 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1709238 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:70530 (70.5 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:dd400000-dd420000
```

I don't have an IPV4 address, So I guess that means the DHCP doesn't receive the request or can't send it.

**$ cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Seems good, I also tried to add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I got the same result.

**$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

If I put managed=true, I get an ifupdown connection that I can't set up.

**$ journalctl -f**

```
Jul 07 18:35:05 toromachine dhclient[22025]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x6a052979)
Jul 07 18:35:09 toromachine dhclient[22025]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x6a052979)
Jul 07 18:35:19 toromachine dhclient[22025]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x6a052979)
Jul 07 18:35:37 toromachine dhclient[22025]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x6a052979)
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <warn> [1499477747.7752] dhcp4 (eth0): request timed out
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.7753] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8079] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 22025
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8079] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8086] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8091] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <warn> [1499477747.8098] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'eth0'
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8113] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8151] policy: auto-activating connection 'eth0'
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8166] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (e7361020-1796-4583-aab9-9d479aac94fe)
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8167] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8168] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8170] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8180] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8182] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477747.8206] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 22043
Jul 07 18:35:47 toromachine dhclient[22043]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x15238503)
Jul 07 18:35:50 toromachine dhclient[22043]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x15238503)
Jul 07 18:35:55 toromachine dhclient[22043]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x15238503)
Jul 07 18:36:04 toromachine dhclient[22043]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x15238503)
Jul 07 18:36:15 toromachine dhclient[22043]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x15238503)
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <warn> [1499477792.7707] dhcp4 (eth0): request timed out
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7708] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7874] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 22043
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7875] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7881] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7885] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <warn> [1499477792.7891] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'eth0'
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7902] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7937] policy: auto-activating connection 'eth0'
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7945] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (e7361020-1796-4583-aab9-9d479aac94fe)
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7954] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7955] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7958] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7969] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7971] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 07 18:36:32 toromachine NetworkManager[19050]: <info> [1499477792.7984] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 22057
```

For me, it can't send the request to the DHCP server. But it seems to discover some DHCP.

**$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state**

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

Seems good. I manually desactivate the wireless.

**$ sudo dhcpdump -i eth0**

```
TIME: 2017-07-12 17:24:55.942
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (c:51:1:e2:30:2b) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 14ac6666
  SECS: 3
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 0c:51:01:e2:30:2b:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      86400 (24h)
OPTION:  12 ( 33) Host name                 dcs-airporttimecapsule-3042bainer
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                          2 (Time offset)
                          3 (Routers)
                         15 (Domainname)
                          6 (DNS server)
                         12 (Host name)
                         44 (NetBIOS name server)

OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 1500
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:0c:51:01:e2:30:2b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope someone will have some ideas to help me.

Comment: I wonder what happens if NetworkManger stopped. `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop`

Comment: The setup is exactly the same but instead to have the only eth0 doesn't work, I have also the wireless disabled.

Comment: After network manager is stopped or disabled, sth else happens?